# /usr/bin/dpkg was accidentally deleted

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, dpkg, debian-jessie

I accidentally deleted my `/usr/bin/dpkg` on my raspberry pi running debian jessie, I've literally checked out everything, nothing works, I need urgent help.

When I attempt to install any package, or even run a `dpkg` command I get something like:

```
open (2:/usr/dpkg/lock does not exist
```

Comment: If you’ve “literally checked out everything”, there’s not a lot anyone else
can do. If you haven’t checked *everything*, you should edit your question to include details of what you have actually tried – and the results. You have to provide relevant details if you want others to help you. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3):

First download the package `dpkg`:

```
apt-get download dpkg
```

Now you see the `.deb` package in your current working directory. This can be unpacked manually by:

```
ar x dpkg_<package_version>.deb
```

That package containes, amongst other things, a file called `data.tar.gz`. In there are the executables. Unpack it within the current directory:

```
tar xf data.tar.gz
```

Your desired executable is now in `./usr/bin/dpkg` and can be copied back with:

```
cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/dpkg
```

Your binary is back and can therefore be called by a shell:

```
dpkg --version
```

Comment: Very good answer, except the actual format of that `data.*` bundle might be different. For instance, Jessie mostly (or exclusively) uses `xz` format which is to be unpacked using the `xz` package.

Comment: returns bash: dpkg: command not found, I definitely screwed something up REALLY bad.

Comment: @icecreamscoop At which step? Where the other steps successful? What about calling `/usr/bin/dpkg`?

Comment: @kostix I did that on a debian 8 (Jesse). The data.* file was a tar gzip archive.

Comment: @chaos It says "/usr/bin/dpkg: is a directory"

Comment: @icecreamscoop Remove that directory: `rm -R /usr/bin/dpkg`. And then do again: `cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/dpkg` from that directory where the deb file was.

Comment: @chaos, on my Jessie system (amd64) running `ar t /var/cache/apt/archives/dpkg-dev_1.17.25_all.deb | grep data` returns `data.tar.xz`. See also the `-Z` command-line option [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg-deb.1.html).

Comment: I had to set the executable bit: `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dpkg`, but I was running a debian derivitive appliance OS, which might be the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Oh you poor unfortunate sudoer... However, this can be fixed!

First off, you need to know whether your Pi uses armel or armhf this can be found with a quick google search with the model of your Pi. Example: `Raspberry pi 2 armel or armhf` (Sorry, I don't know off the top of my head...)

To get the armel version of the file run:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.25_armel.deb
```

For the armhf:

```
wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.17.25_armhf.deb
```

Once it downloads use the command:

```
ar -x <package name>
```

This will extract a few files. The one you want is `data.tar.gz` extract it by using:

```
tar xf data.tar.gz
```

You now have a `usr/` and `sbin/` directory. One last command:

```
sudo cp usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/dpkg
```

*Notice the positioning of the "/" in the last part of that command*

Now you should again have the dpkg package back and be able to install packages to your heart's content.

Hope this Helps!

Answer (score -1):

Since all the solutions I tried didn't work (including the 2 which were posted here), I had to reinstall the OS on my raspberry pi using NOOBS. Thanks for all the help though.

Comment: The solution posted by @chaos works. I've tried it myself.

Comment: If anyone feels this doesn't work - make sure that /usr/bin/dpkg is executable: `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/dpkg`